# Python: only run command once in for loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which creates a CSV of values of several files in a directory.

Within this loop I only want to create the file and write in the header once, currently I am doing this:

```
    #name&path to table file
    test = tablefile+"/"+str(cell[:-10])+"_Table.csv"

    #write file
    if not os.path.isfile(test):
        csv.writer(open(test, "wt"))         
        with open(test, 'w') as output:
            wr = csv.writer(output, lineterminator=',')
            for val in header_note:
                wr.writerow([val])
```

and to append data I have:

```
        with open(test, 'a') as output:
        wr = csv.writer(output, lineterminator=',')
        for val in table_all:
            wr.writerow([val])
```

Which works well, however, when I run the script over again another time it will append more data to the bottom of that same .csv. What I want is for the first time through the for-loop, is to just overwrite any existing .csv with a new one with a header then continue on appending data, and overwrite/re-write header once the script is run again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It look like you may have some code problems other than file handling, but here goes:  You problem is basically that opening a file in `'w'` mode will overwrite everything in the file, and opening in `'a'` mode will not allow you to change the header line.

To get around this, you will have to get the contents of the file (if it already exists), *then* overwrite the file, including those lines that where there to begin with.

You will want something along the lines of:

```
if os.path.exists(file_name):           # if file already exists
  with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file: # open it
    old_lines = in_file.readlines()[1:] # read all lines from file EXCEPT header line

with open(file_name, 'w') as out_file: # open file again, with 'w' to create/overwrite
  out_file.write(new_header_line)       # write new header line to file
  for line in old_lines:
    out_file.write(line)                # write all preexisting lines back into file
  # continue writing whatever you want.
```